# TCP/IP over Serial Port

Tags: serial-port, ip

I am trying to setup a network interface over one of serialports of the system.

I am using beaglebone and Xbee-wifi modules. Basically I'm trying to communicate 2 beaglebone over serialport bu using a TCP/IP protocole.

I need to connect to the beaglebone via ssh, telnet or via default web port 80. So I do not need a single port working on the serial interface. I need a newtork intarface running over serialport.

Is there anyway to do this?

Hardware : beaglebone black
os : angstrom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the manual setup I have, run this command:

```
pppd proxyarp mtu 1280 persist nodeflate noauth lcp-echo-interval 10 crtscts lock 10.10.1.2:10.10.1.1 /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

on one host, and the same command on the other host with the IP addressed swapped. You should now have a `ppp0` interface on both machines.

- You need a null modem cable between the machines
- Make sure you use the correct /dev/ entry and speed for the serial port
- Embedded systems tend to configure a serial port as the kernel console, where kernel messages are written, and perhaps configure getty for login sessions over serial as well - you might need to find a way to disable those.

Setting up [slip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol) instead of ppp might be an alternative too.

Answer (score 0):

By some reason pppd receipt not working on Raspberry PI and Orange PI.

So found working solution via [Slip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol):

```
sudo slattach -p slip -s 115200 /dev/ttyAMA0 &
sudo ifconfig sl0 10.10.1.1 pointopoint 10.10.1.2 up
```

on second machine just swap IP's addresses